# How to extract numerical value after a certain string within a sentence in Excel cell?

Tags: database, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I want to extract **the numerical value immediately following the string "ABS" (Case sensitive)** within a bulk of text in a cell from an Excel table.

Not all the cell may contain the the string I'm looking for, so a filter is required.

The contents of the cell look something like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ante
>   mi, laoreet nec tristique et, sodales at dui. Vestibulum ullamcorper
>   augue at nibh auctor laoreet ornare nisi posuere. Aliquam convallis
>   nisl auctor mauris pharetra faucibus. Nullam nulla dolor, varius
>   viverra facilisis nec, viverra in tortor.  Integer sollicitudin, elit
>   in tempor interdum, sapien justo luctus justo, id varius nisi mauris
>   at ipsum. Vivamus tincidunt neque sed felis accumsan tempus.
>
> ABS: 1.5, ADS: 2.5, SR: 11
>
> Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
>   fames ac turpis egestas. Integer vestibulum felis et lorem pretium
>   molestie. Nulla imperdiet, magna vel accumsan ornare, augue quam
>   ornare justo, vitae volutpat turpis orci quis nibh. Nullam vitae diam
>   et ligula commodo pretium. Etiam et luctus dui.

The trouble is since the contents are entered manually, they may vary in structure, with slight variations such as:

> ABS : 1.5 (Space after ABS)

or

> ABS is 1.5 ('is' instead of colon)

or

> ABS = 1.5 ('=' instead of colon)

or

> ABS 1.5 (numerical value immediately after text without colon)

....etc

The numerical value is between 0-8.5 with increments of 0.5, (i.e. 0, 0.5, 1.0, ... 7.5, 8.0, 8.5).

I have tried a combination of left() and find() functions but don't know how to just extract the numbers after finding the string "ABS". If someone can help or point me in a direction, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: What is the maximum number that you would encounter in the text string in the cell (if there is one)?

Comment: 0-8.5 with increments of 0.5, (0, 0.5, 1.0, ... 7.5, 8.0, 8.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula finds `ABS`....then finds the first numeric value after that and then takes the number that starts there (up to 5 characters)

`=LOOKUP(10^10,MID(A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&1234567890,FIND("ABS",A1))),{1,2,3,4,5})+0)`

Assumes data in A1

If the number might be longer than 5 characters then extend the `{1,2,3,4,5}` part

If you want to avoid error if ABS isn't found then try wrapping in IFERROR function

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(10^10,MID(A1,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1&1234567890,FIND("ABS",A1))),{1,2,3,4,5})+0),"")`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked great, however, is there a way that the function just displays null (blank) when ABS is not found?

Comment: If you have Excel 2007 or later you can wrap an IFERROR function around it - I edited my reply

Comment: A very helpful answer. I modified it to use SEARCH instead of FIND (case sensitive) because the text being looked for had variations in being all lower case, initial cap then lower or all caps.