# Excel: extracting a number from mixed content cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, extract, cells

How would one extract a number starting with a "£" sign from a cell containing alphanumeric characters?

Example: extracting £450,000 from A1 and placing in B1. See image for example text

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract numerical value after a certain string within a sentence in Excel cell](http://superuser.com/q/559535/354511). See also [Extract numbers from cells containing mixed alpha-numeric strings](http://superuser.com/q/649475/354511), [Extracting multiple numerical values from mixed characters in Excel worksheet](http://superuser.com/q/740171/354511), and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have a **space** after the number, then in **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("£",A1,1)+1,9999)
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=MID(B1,1,FIND(" ",B1)-1)
```

For example:

[image]